# App works but the Django Admin page is not accessible - DoesNotExist at /admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

So everything was working fine. Now I get

```
>     DoesNotExist at /admin
>     IsoControls matching query does not exist.
```

In my console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:....\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\.....\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:.....\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\.....\controls_app\views.py", line 26, in testing
    testing_sheet = IsoControls.objects.get(slug=slug)
  File "C:\.....\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\.....\models\query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
controls_app.models.IsoControls.DoesNotExist: IsoControls matching query does not exist.
```

So I checked line line 26 in views.py. Which is:

```
 if request.method == "GET":
        testing_sheet = IsoControls.objects.get(slug=slug)
        form = forms.ControlTesting(instance=testing_sheet)
        return render(request, 'controls_app/testing_sheet.html', {'form':form, 'testing_sheet':testing_sheet})
    else:
        testing_sheet = IsoControls.objects.get(slug=slug)
        form = forms.ControlTesting(request.POST, instance=testing_sheet)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, 'controls_app/testing_sheet.html', {'form':form, 'testing_sheet':testing_sheet})
```

the local site works just fine. Only if I go to the /admin page - I get these errors. I cannot access the admin page anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out. In my URLs I had

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'), 
    path('<slug:slug>', views.testing, name='testing')
]
```

So - /admin was (I assume) getting routed as a slug. I changed to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'), 
    path('testing_sheet/<slug:slug>', views.testing, name='testing')
]
```

And everything is working fine now.